# AutoFill SQL Server from Datagridview c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have datagridview that connects to a database in SQL Server.

In the database, I have 2 columns `NumCrimCase` and `Prosecutor`
where I need to fill `Prosecutor`

| NumCrimCase | Prosecutor |
| --- | --- |
| 51-4462 км 23 | уффуа |
| 51-4540 км 23 |  |
| 51-4609 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4540 км 23 |  |
| 51-4609 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |

You can see in `NumCrimCase` I have the same data and in `Prosecutor` I have empty rows.

For example:

filled row

| NumCrimCase | Prosecutor |
| --- | --- |
| 51-4462 км 23 | уффуа |

and another unfilled row

| NumCrimCase | Prosecutor |
| --- | --- |
| 51-4462 км 23 |  |

when `NumCrimCase` contains the same data.

I need to fill all same `NumCrimCase` into `Prosecutor` for all the same rows, and my form has a button that should do that.

I don't have idea how I can do it.

I tried sorting my columns by `NumCrimCase`, and fill rows latest values. That doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't work here either, you should explain what happens. It should be a simple loop in pseudo code: `var lastValue = null; for(int i = 0; i < rows.size; i++) if (rows[i] == null) {rows[i] = lastValue;} lastValue = rows[i]; }` You can handle NumCrimCase the same way so it only sets if NumCrimCase  is same as previous

Comment: Please don't use images the editor provides code formatting and table markdown

Comment: @siggemannen why rows.size?

Comment: How would you loop through all rows? Note, pseudo code means it doesn't compile, it just a sample idea

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78073228/edit) feature. Don't delete and repost questions, *improve* them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to fill the Prosecutor column for rows with the same data in the NumCrimCase column, correct? You can solve this using an SQL query. For example, to update the Prosecutor column with the same value for all rows with the same NumCrimCase, you can use the following query:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Prosecutor = (SELECT TOP 1 Prosecutor FROM table_name AS t2 WHERE t2.NumCrimCase = table_name.NumCrimCase)
```

This query retrieves the Prosecutor value from any row with the same NumCrimCase for each row and updates all rows with that value. Of course, you should replace "table_name" with the name of your table. You can then connect this query to a button in your application to execute it when needed.

Comment: if i need take last date, not  `select top 1` how i can change it?